# How do I make my http://localhost:1234/ have a page instead of having to go to http://localhost:1234/index?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I'm unable to find an answer as to how to make the localhost url as my base page. Hence, to access my page, it has to be localhost:1234/index or some other page which I want to avoid.

Comment: For whatever web server you are using, you need to look in to `Default Document` or `Default Page` - Not a programming question, but one of configuration of your web server

Comment: I have set my index.aspx as a start page, but it brings me to that still.

Comment: A Start Page is not the Default Page. It sounds like you are looking in Visual Studio debug property pages and not the Web Server configuration settings

Comment: I think we need to know more than this. Depending on your situation you could use `@page "/"` but this obviously only works if you're using something that supports this syntax.

Comment: If its IIS set the default document to index.aspx .

Answer (score 0):

To make your web server could accessed with `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, you need to bind the web server to port `80`

Here is how to check and set port binding in IIS

https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO9987.html